# How to scrape text value in label tag which is inside div tag using selenium with python?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have tried multiple things present on stackoverflow but nothing worked out for me.

Here is the pattern of the HTML

```
<div class="single-model">
<label> MacBook<lable>
<div>

<div class="single-model">
<label> MacBook Air<lable>
<div>

<div class="single-model">
<label> MacBook Air Pro<lable>
<div>
```

I want to extract out the model names present in `<label>` tag inside `<div class= "single-model">`

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

Brand = ["Apple"]
model_name = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

search_url="https://northladder.com/en/ae/electronics/laptop/apple"
driver.get(search_url)

#Scroll to the end of the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)

modelname = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="single-model")
for m in modelname:
    model = m.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="label")
    print(model.text)
```

Here `print(model.text)`
is giving me an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

[find_elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_elements#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements)  gives you a list of elements not a single element (even if there's only 1 match found) so you would need to loop over the elements to get the text inside it

```py
for m in modelname:
    models = m.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="label")
    for modal in modals:
        print(model.text)
```

alternatively if you only want to find 1 label per loop you can use [find_element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_element#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) instead of [find_elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_elements#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements) and then it will only give you 1

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
modelname = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label")
for m in modelname:
    model= m.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    Model_name.append(model)
print(Model_name)
```